# MySql EF6 with IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-identity

I try to use MS Identity with an MySql Databse and Code-First.

My DbContext Class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class TestDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public TestDbContext()
    {
    }

    public TestDbContext(string cnString)
        : base(cnString)
    {
    }
}
```

My App Config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDbContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=test;uid=root;password=root"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

If i use the normal DbContext its works with Code-First Migrations. But if i change to IdentityDbContext and i try to "Update-Database" i get the following Error:

> Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of the
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory,
>   EntityFramework' type as specified in the application configuration.
>   See inner exception for details.

How can i get MS Identity to work with MySql?

Ok i have change the DefaultConnectionFactory to

```
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
```

but now i get another Error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Ok i get the Database Connection to work but the Identity Tables such as aspnetuser won't create automaticly.

Comment: If your context is inheriting from IdentityDbContext it should create the identity tables for you - no need for separate migrations. Also, your defaultConnectionFactory does not appear correct for MySql (<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></defaultConnectionFactory>)

Comment: Now it works but the aspnet* tables are not automatically generated.